# Why Option B) is incorrect?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $f\left(x\right)\le x^5$ be a continuous function for all x $\epsilon$ **R** then $f\left(x\right)$ is

A) All answers are wrong

B) The integral average of $f(x)$ is on $[0,1]$ is positive

C) The integral average of $f(x)$ is on $[0,1]$ is negative

D) The integral average of $f(x)$ is on $[-1,0]$ is positive

E) The integral average of $f(x)$ is on $[-1,0]$ is negative

for my opinion , Both B) and E) are right since I applied integral formula on $x^5$ giving two results

Comment: Technically, A) runs into the liar paradox :)

Comment: Ignoring that, E) is the only right answer ( C) is wrong, consider $f(x)=x^5$ and D) is wrong, consider also $f(x)=x^5$)

Comment: E is the correct answer, because $f$ is bounded above by function whos integral is negative on $[-1,0]$

Comment: I don't understand I meant to write C and E but it was confusion which to select

Comment: **@fGDu94** but if we take  [0,1] why we cannot say that 
  is bounded above by function whos integral is on [0,1] is positive

Comment: sure we can, its just that $f$ could be for example $f(x) = -1$ on $[0,1]$, so we can't be sure has a positive integral on $[0,1]$. Meanwhile you could have $f(x) = x^5$ on $[0,1]$ as well, which is positive.

Comment: can I go for option c also then

Comment: no because $f(x) = x^5$ is a counterexample

Comment: I now understand sir but last question f(x)=1 on  [-1,0] we also cannot be sure

Comment: $f(x) \leq x^5$ on $[-1,0]$.

Therefore $\int_{-1}^0 f(x) \leq \int_{-1}^0 x^5 dx = \frac{-1}{6} < 0$.

Comment: thanks sir got it , b is incorrect because  f(x) **can be**negative on [0,1] and e is right because f(x) **is** negative on [-1,0] so we can be sure